# Как правильно собрать данные из списка групп полей

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Всем привет, есть вопрос. Разрабатываю приложуху. У меня на странице есть кнопка добавить форму, по нажатию на которую собсветнно добавляется форма, сама форма - отдельный компонет, у нее есть поля. Таких форм может быть много. И у меня проблема в том, что я не знаю как прокидывать стейт полей каждой формы в родительский компонент.

В родительском компоненте находится стейт всех форм

```
const [forms, setForms] = useState([]);

return (
  forms.map(form => <Form key={form.id} />)
)
```

В дочернем компоненте() у меня также есть поля:

```
const [driverFullname, setDriverFullname] = useState('');
const [sex, setSex] = useState('');
```

Подскажите как прокидывать стейт из компонента формы в стейт родительского компонента?

Comment: Так для начала вам необходимо определиться с принципом работы. А так, что первое приходит в голову, можно по таймауту. Например, пользователь не вводит данные 3 секунды и  можно обновить состояние. Но я не понимаю зачем динамические данные хранить в состоянии?

Comment: Переписал вопрос

Comment: Вариант хранить стейт самой формы (driverFullname и sex) в родителе и пропсами кидать в сам Form?

Comment: А разве я что-то должен прокидывать в пропс? У меня же внутри формы есть состояния полей, они по дефолту пустые. Мне нужно их заполнить и каким-то образом обратно отправить в родительский компонент

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте компоненту формы коллбек `onChange`, который будет возвращать объект с содержимым полей после окончания ввода.

> Для оптимизации, можно принимать собранные данные с задержкой

```
(function() {

  const {
    useEffect,
    useState,
  } = React;

  const Form = ({
    onChange = (data) => console.log({data}),
  }) => {

    const [driverFullname, setDriverFullname] = useState('');
    const [sex, setSex] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => onChange({
        driverFullname, sex,
      }), 1000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, [driverFullname, sex]);

  };

})();
```